# adjustResize not happening

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

My manifest file looks like

```
<activity 
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:icon="@drawable/ew_logo"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"          
            android:name="activity.MainActivity">
        </activity>
```

My Mainactivity contains custom toolbar and Edittext in vertical orientation. When keyboard popouts in HTC(landscape mode), am able to see only edittext not toolbar. I want the view like adjustresize not adjust pane.

Comment: sure you have wrapped your layout in scrollview ?

Comment: Yes. Am using scrollview which contains relativelayout as child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. `mEditText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI);`

You can also do it from the xml file using

```
android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
```

From the documentation

> For input methods that may be fullscreen, often when in landscape mode, this allows them to be smaller and let part of the application be shown behind.

Comment: Thanks. Its works great. Shall i need a scrollview and android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" changes still?

Answer (score 0):

Whats the activity layout you're using? you should wrap it with scrollview for adjustResize to work.